# Why do i need to left shift before summing the result?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

Here is a code snippet that works as intended, it correctly reverses the bits of an integer and returns the new int. My question is why does the line `result <<= 1` have to occur before I sum result with the operation `n&1`?

In the first iteration, it does not affect results because the result is instantiated as 0. If I put the `result <<= 1` line at the END of the for loop, I would still be left shifting result before I sum result with `n&1`.
My code, with the left shifting result at the end, isn't working and I can't seem to understand this final step.

```
public int reverseBits(int n) {
    int result = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<32; i++){
        result <<= 1;
        result += n&1;
        n >>= 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: it is not "needed", just easier to leave it there since needed in subsequent iterations. If it was put at the end (inside) of the loop, it must be undone outside/after the loop. (also would risk loosing the first bit)

Comment: somehow this can be compared with summing values, we often use `sum = sum + value` (or `sum += value`) which is not needed for first iteration, just *easier* to let it there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first iteration it indeed has no effect, but thats okay, thats intended. It is better, than writing `if (i != 0) result <<= 1;`. That would be inefficient to check this in every iteration. But also important to note this that essentially out of the 32 iteration only in 31 it will have an effect and should. So if you put the `result <<= 1;` line in the end than make sure it is only executing effectively 31 times also keeping in mind, that now it should execute in the first iteration since the order changed, but it should not in the last iteration. That is the reason why the result will be invalid.

Try this. This will work.

```
public int reverseBits(int n) {
    int result = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<32; i++){
        result += n&1;
        n >>= 1;
        if (i != 31) // skip the shift in last iteration
            result <<= 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because otherwise you operate on the wrong bit of your operation. Note you could replace your current bitshifts with simple arithmetic and division if that helps. Like,

```
public static int reverseBits(int n) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        result += result + (n & 1);
        n /= 2;
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Explanation<sup>1</sup>:**

```
result <<= 1;
```

This is equivalent to `result = result * 2`, which is the same as `result = result + result` thus we can combine with the next instruction;

```
result += n&1
```

and get

```
result += result + (n & 1);
```

As for `>>= 1`, that is the same as `/ 2`.

<sup>**1**</sup><sub>Math.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

This is a one-off problem:

- you need to copy 32 bits, so you're doing 32 `result += n&1;`operations (0..31)
- to move the rightmost bit (position 0) to the leftmost position (position 31) you only need to do **31** left-shift operations.

Therefore, putting the `result <<= 1;` at the beginning is fine, as it actually does nothing, as there is nothing yet in `result`, so you're doing only 31 left-shifts.
Only when you move it after the `result += n&1;` you're doing 32 left-shift operations, loosing one bit.
The same holds for the `n >>= 1;`, where you do 32 right-shift operations as well, but the final right-shift doesn't matter, as it is never added to the result (and zero anyway).